# Cross Site Publishing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have enabled Cross Site Publishing feature. In the first site collection, I have enabled pages library as Catalog. In the another site collection I am connecting to the first site collection. Pages and manage data term is created in another site collection.

Now the problem is that I have to create my own custom application page in the second site collection. The application page should work as the Content by Search Web Part. How can I do that programmatically? How to read data from search?

Comment: You question is a little confusing.  You don't deploy an application page to a site collection, you deploy it to the whole farm.  It sounds like what you really want is a site page with a content by query web part.

Comment: Question is very confusing can you elaborate more with screen shot or with more description